# Passing route parameter through button to another page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I am using materialui library along with react-router. In my top-level component, I have my routes specified:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const {classes} = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment> 
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Route render={({location}) => (
          <TransitionGroup>
          <CSSTransition
              key={location.key}
              timeout={100}
              classNames="someanimation"
            >
          <Switch location={location}>
               <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
               <Route exact path="/customer/:id" component={CustomerPage} />
               <Route component={ErrorPage} />
             </Switch>
           </CSSTransition>
         </TransitionGroup>
       )} />
        </BrowserRouter>
     </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

On my home page, I have some buttons which correspond to some customers. When I click the button it should now go to the customers' page with that customer id. My home page button looks like this:

```
<Button component={Link} to="/customer/:id">
                      Go To Customer id : {this.props.customer[100]}
                    </Button>
```

From here I am unsure how to pass the customer id from this button to the customer page now?

My customer page is simple and looks like this:

```
const Customer= () => {
    return(
        <div >
            <h3>Customer ID : {somehow get the id that was passed in here}</h3>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: React router has a match props that passes the parameters from the URL. So if you have a props called `id`, it should be `this.props.match.params.id`

Comment: On the button how do I specify which id I want to pass?

Comment: your 'to='/customer/${this.props.customer[100]}''. You have to pass the value to the link. Just replace the quotes with string literals

Answer (score 1):

The `to` prop on your button needs to specify the exact route URL, not the path. So something like:

```
<Button component={Link} to="/customer/100">
```

Then as Strahinja Ajvaz mentioned in the comments, you can use `this.props.match.params.id` in your `Customer` component to retrieve that id

Comment: It does not seem to work. My button look like this now: <Button component={Link} to="/customer/${customer[100]}">  and in the customer page I have the following: <h3>ID : {this.props.match.params.id}</h3>. I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Comment: so I changed it to match.params.id and it shows up if I enter the url directly (e.g customer/100), setting it up from my button is still not working for dyanmic ids. Yes if I put to="/customer/100" but I need it to allow an expression since the id's are not hardocded byt dynamic

Comment: FIgured it out: to={'/customer/' + customer[100]}